# How to suppress only user keyboard and mouse input with pynput?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, pynput

I want to type some words with pynput but when pynput typing the user shouldn't use the keyboard and mouse. After pynput wrote some words, the keyboard and mouse will be enabled again.

I wrote a code like below, the code is preventing user input but also preventing itself too, so pynput cannot type anything. I want to prevent only user input. Is this possible?

```
import pynput

mouse_listener = pynput.mouse.Listener(suppress=True)
keyboard_listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(suppress=True)
mouse_listener.start()
keyboard_listener.start()

keyboard = pynput.keyboard.Controller()
keyboard.type("Hello world")
mouse_listener.stop()
keyboard_listener.stop()
```